# Win10 - how to restore deleted WinRM service?

Tags: services, winrm, windows-10

I have deleted by mistake the WinRM service from a WIN 10 machine, How can I restore it ?
Is there some installation \ sc.exe command I can run to recreated it or can it be done by adding windows feature ?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management) is the Microsoft documentation on the subject

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't find the relevant part that can help solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to import
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WinRM registry key from another machine that don't have this issue.

Comment: I just had to restart computer after, but it worked.